# Multiplication of 2 decimal number values Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, precision

I am doing multiplication of 2 values in Objective c which seems very simple yes but the result i get after multiplication is not correct the last digit after decimal point is changing the value. The code i used to do multiplication is below.

```
NSDecimalNumber* x = rpnStack.back(); rpnStack.pop_back();
NSDecimalNumber* y = rpnStack.back(); rpnStack.pop_back();
NSDecimalNumber* z = [y decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:x]; // y * x;
```

The value of x = 20.16
The value of y = 51.3934970238095
The result of z is = 1036.0928999999995, which is should be 1036.0928999999996 as tested in many calculators. Can anyone give me some hint how can i fix this last number ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I get the correct value by using `NSNumber` instead of `NSDecimalNumber`

```
NSNumber *x = @(20.16);
NSNumber *y = @(51.3934970238095);
NSNumber *z = @(x.doubleValue * y.doubleValue); //1036.0928999999996
```

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question. He specifically asked about `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: @yassir using NSNumber i got this result 1036.0929, I am wondering how you are able to print all the 13 characters after decimal. Can you explain ?

Comment: @AshleyMills can be any other datatype, if it works.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand the OPs question. I thought he asked for a Solution but i didn't understand that the use of `NSDecimalNumber` was required :)

Comment: @AbbasZahid you got `1036.0929` because of `NSNumber description` implementation. Try to print the `NSNumber doubleValue` then you'll see the 13 characters after decimal. :)

Comment: @AbbasZahid i think it's the `NSNumber stringValue` implementation. With `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.13f",z.doubleValue]` i got `1036.0928999999996`

Comment: There are too many digits (18) in the result to do this calculation precisely using `double` (15-17 digits). So your result is as imprecise as those of the OP's calculators.

Comment: @Yassir yes it is stringValue implementation and it works this way. but i still dont understand why some calculators give value 96 instead of 95 as done by hand it is 95. Anyway thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

NSDecimalNumber provides the correct answer. Try verifying the result by hand.

```
    51.3934970238095
  * 20.16
  --------------------
     3.083609821428570
     5.13934970238095
     0.0
+ 1027.869940476190
----------------------
  1036.092899999999520
```

Comment: it is correct but why some calculators are not giving this result ? They change the value 95 to 96 in the end.

Comment: @AbbasZahid That's because of computational limitations on the calculator.

Answer (score 1):

When you print `NSDecimalNumber` in console it rounds according to rounding behavior provided, usually default. Please refer to `NSNumberFormatter` and `NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode` when printing `NSDecimalNumbers`.

See:

1. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber?language=objc
2. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumberhandler
3. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumberformatter